# Importing file from Blender to Unreal Engine

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, unreal-engine, motion-capture

I have a few characters with complex rigs that work in conjunction with wrinkle maps.

I’m looking to transfer them to Unreal Engine for use with motion capture.

I need the wrinkle maps and their corresponding mask image maps, as well as topology, nodes, drivers, shape keys and UV layout to stay the same. Is there a way to transfer all of these components in Blender to Unreal Engine and have the same character and rig in Unreal?

For instance when I open the character in Unreal Engine, will all of those components have transferred or will I need to redo them?

Forgive my lack of knowledge in Unreal Engine, I’m not familiar with it.

Comment: Simple answer: No. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures which covers animation as well as just textures.